# Plotly order add_trace

Tags: r, plotly

Depending on the order in which I introduce the add_trace my graph is different.
This is a problem for me because I work with a shiny R application that adds the beginning of ploty in a variable and then I add a second add_trace with the user's values. So I can't reverse the order.

Would you have an idea to avoid this ?

Reproducible example attached:

```
library(plotly)

df <- read.table(text="
    Product        variable value
1 ProductA             DDD    24
2 ProductB             DDD    22
3 ProductB             DDD    35
5 ProductA Brandattention    29
6 ProductB Brandattention    27
7 ProductBe Brandattention    27", header = TRUE)
```

order that causes me problems

```
df %>% plot_ly()%>%

  add_trace(x = ~variable, y = ~value, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines',line = list(color = 'red', width = 1))%>%
  add_trace(x = ~variable, y = ~value, type = 'bar', 
               color = ~Product, 
               colors = c("ProductA" = "yellow", 
                          "ProductB" = "blue"))
```

[image: bad order]

Good order

```
df %>% plot_ly()%>%

  add_trace(x = ~variable, y = ~value, type = 'bar', 
               color = ~Product, 
               colors = c("ProductA" = "yellow", 
                          "ProductB" = "blue"))%>%
  add_trace(x = ~variable, y = ~value, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines',line = list(color = 'red', width = 1))
```

[image: good order]

Comment: The code you include is nice, but I can't work out what you're trying to do or what's going wrong?

Comment: I am forced to execute my code in the order that generates the wrong plot. 
I would like to find a way to do this without changing the order of the add_traces

Comment: I think I'm close to the goal by putting the start in a variable but I don't know how to add_data() which seems to allow this   `    a=plot_ly()%>%add_trace(x = ~variable, y = ~value, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines')

  df %>% plot_ly()%>%
  add_trace(x = ~variable, y = ~value, type = 'bar',color = ~Product, 
                                                                colors = c("ProductA" = "yellow", 
                                                                           "ProductB" = "blue"))%>%add_data(a)`

Comment: I don't know how to solve, but I do understand your question better now. Would you mind if I edit it to make it easier for other to understand? (you can always change it back if you prefer the original wording)

Comment: Yes of course thank you

Comment: So I understand this better, you are trying to have the line trace hard-coded in your shiny dashboard and create the bars based on user input? or the other way around?

Comment: Can I double check something. Is this line in your data correct? `7 ProductBe Brandattention    27", header = TRUE)` (particularly the "ProductBe" part) - just want to make sure it's not a typo because the plots look very different if it's changed to "ProductB".

Comment: M-- : I create the beginning of the plotly in a reactive function and save it in a reactivevalues and in the renderplotly function I call this reactivevalues and I add the barplot which is also issued in dataframe saved in a reactivevalues .

Comment: stevec : Yes, this was intentional for other tests (not coloring a Product when no specify in Colors list).

Comment: RESOLVED. With a little rest I managed to correct my problem. Just put the colors argument in the plot_ly function as it does not belong to add_traces. Thank you for accepting to help me.